# c# AddMemoryPressure memory leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I wrote the test. And run it on net5 and net472.
dotMemory shows growth in unmanaged Memory.

```
var size = 1920 * 1080 * 3 / 2;

for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    GC.AddMemoryPressure(size);
    GC.RemoveMemoryPressure(size);
    Thread.Sleep(1);
}
```

Is it a memory leak?
Why is dotMemory showing this?

[image: net472]

[image: net5]

Comment: `Is it memory leak?` - [no](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203).

Comment: @GSerg but I don't allocate memory, where does it come from?

Comment: Probabily it might be an overhead from the becnhmark framework itself. It does a lot of low level disassembly to get precise numbers. I tried replicate your scenario in .NET 7 and this didn't happen

Comment: By the way why are your messing around with garbage collector on your own? Are your sure is it necessary? It's very rare C# coders invoke by themselves GC methods on their on even in performance critic operations.

Comment: @DouglasFerreira I tried .NET 7 - the picture is the same. I have a lot of legacy code where this is used. The code counts the number of objects, at a certain value the collector is called. I'm trying to locate leaks unmanagenet memory. I already fixed some thanks to DebugDiag, but this graph is confusing.

Comment: dotMemory can have impact on the monitored application. I would not claim that it is the reason for this particular behaviour but I've seen GC pauses spiking significantly due to usage of the tool.

Comment: Can't you see any particular object in dotMemory taking a signicatly piece of memory?

Comment: @DouglasFerreira dotMemory  doesn't show unmanagement memory objects. I'm trying to focus on the number of objects that are associated with unmanaged memory

Comment: Have you tried the in-build VS memory profiler? I think it does provides some more details about unmanaged references than dotMemory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dotMemory derives `Unmanaged memory` from `Total used` minus all managed memory. `Total used` is based on RSS (resident set size):

| Memory Category | Usage |
| --- | --- |
| Total used | 14.2 MB |
| Unmanaged memory | 13.6 MB |
| Heap generation 0 | 24.0 B |
| Heap generation 1 | 24.0 B |
| Heap generation 2 | 335.1 KB |
| LOH and POH | 312.1 KB |

```
USER             PID  %CPU %MEM       VSZ    RSS   TT  STAT STARTED      TIME COMMAND
user           28318  15.0  0.1 410585360  14572 s002  S+   12:21AM  23:02.94 test
```

`Total used = RSS/1024 = 14572/1024 = 14.23 MB`

`Unmanaged memory = Total used - Heap* - LOH and POH = 14.2-(24*2/1024/1024+335.1/1024+312.1/1024) = 13.56 MB`

So, any native allocation/deallocation can affect `Unmanaged memory`. In the context of your sample, the most likely cause of unexpected RSS volatility/growth is the dotMemory agent library injected into the target process. A straightforward way to narrow down the source is to run the sample with and without dotMemory. I used .NET Core (7.0.305) for a 25 minute comparison based on the sample you provided:

##### Without dotMemory

[image: withoutdotmemory]

##### With dotMemory (libJetBrains.Profiler.Core.dylib loaded)

[image: withdotmemory]

[image: ![withdotmemory2]

In the latter case, RSS is higher and considerably more volatile than without the agent. For this sample, the growing unmanaged memory that you observed is most likely caused by the agent.

In my reproduction scenario, where unmanaged memory does not increase throughout the 25 minutes, I used dotMemory 231.9161.46 with JetBrains Rider. However, dotMemory had memory leaks in the past:

https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207774725-dotMemory-and-unmanaged-memory

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DMRY-3915

If you're not using the most recent version, update your installation to rule out that you're still affected by that or related issues. If RSS does not increase without the agent, the agent is to blame. If, however, it does increase without the agent, the runtime or another component that is unique to your .NET installation is causing the issue - highly unlikely.

**Based on the information you provided and my observations, my conclusion is that your dotMemory version causes the unmanaged memory growth.** If not and further investigation is required, I recommend using the valgrind tool massif to visualize the heap growth. Depending on the allocators involved and available symbols, doing so can range from being straightforward (malloc used, symbols are available) to a dead end (custom allocators and missing symbols prevent fine-grained analysis).